# enumerateAssetsWithOptions return an alasset nil

Tags: ios, objective-c, alassetslibrary

i'm getting the user ALAssetsLibrary with this code

```
  ALAssetsLibrary *library = [[ALAssetsLibrary alloc] init];

    // Enumerate just the photos and videos group by using ALAssetsGroupSavedPhotos.
    [library enumerateGroupsWithTypes:ALAssetsGroupSavedPhotos usingBlock:^(ALAssetsGroup *group, BOOL *stop) {
        // Within the group enumeration block, filter to enumerate just photos.
        [group setAssetsFilter:[ALAssetsFilter allPhotos]];

        // Chooses the photo at the last index
        [group enumerateAssetsWithOptions:NSEnumerationReverse usingBlock:^(ALAsset *alAsset, NSUInteger index, BOOL *innerStop) {

            // The end of the enumeration is signaled by asset == nil.
            if (alAsset) {
```

The problem that from time to time the alasset returns as a nil and i have no idea why. Most of the phones i tried it on, it was working fine but for some reason, other phones the alasset just returning as a nil.

Comment: Are all of the phones the same version of iOS?  Do you see any warnings in the debug output?  Did they all grant photos access?

Comment: What is the value of `index` when `alAsset` is `nil`?

Comment: I'm not sure because it's in a phone that i dont have access to. I tried to get the same result in the emulator and index number was 9223372036854775807.
What does in means when the alAsset is nil and the index has a value?

Comment: That's probably `NSNotFound`. `alAsset` will be `nil` and `index` will be `NSNotFound` when the enumeration is done.

Comment: iOS 8.0 has a bug that although there are assets when using index you'll get nil. This was resolved in the later releases. If you want to cover earlier version of iOS 8 what you need to do is fetch all assets and initiate stop when getting to the number of assets you need.

Answer (score 1):

iOS8 introduced the new Photos Framework. Many assets that used to be stored locally on the device are now stored in iCloud (i.e. not on the device). The Photos Framework is intended to be used when interacting with these assets (assets that may or may not be on the device).

My guess is that ALAssetLibrary returns nil for assets not stored locally on the device. Hence the issue you're encountering.

I have heard recently that iOS 8.1 rolled back this iCloud-related change, although I haven't been able to verify myself.

Hope this helps.